# Disable select option when it already selected

Tags: javascript

I have tried to disable the `option` on `select` when it already `selected`. But it didn't `disable` when it already selected.

Below is the `query` for `select option`, it can be created `dynamically`.

```
    var count = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function () {

        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="trrows">';

        html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select name="med_name[]" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option> <?php echo fill_select_box($conn, "0");  ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td id="mor"> <input type="text" name="morning[]" id="morning[]" class="form-control morning" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="noo"> <input type="text" name="noon[]" id="noon[]" class="form-control noon" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="nigh"> <input type="text" name="night[]" id="night[]" class="form-control night" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="period"> <input type="text" name="period[]" id="period[]" class="form-control period" /> </td>';
        html += '<td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove" >  -  </button> </td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#rows').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest("#trrows").remove();
    });
```

Below is the `query` for `disable` the select option on for `(med_name[])`,

```
  $('select[name*="med_name[]"]').change(function(){
  $('select[name*="med_name[]"] option').attr('disabled',false);
  $('select[name*="med_name[]"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('select[name*="med_name[]"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
           $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    });
});

});
```

Below is the HTML,

```
<table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="medical">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Medicine Name</th>
           <th>Morning</th>
           <th>Noon</th>
           <th>Night</th>
           <th>Period</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody id="rows">
         </tbody>
   </table>
       <br><br>

   <div align="right">
   <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn xs"> + </button>
      </div>
```

I don't know where I went wrong. How can I achieve that? Any help may highly appreciated.

Comment: and why you you want to do so when your `select` is not `multiple`

Comment: @brk  I cant understand and get your point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a working example, please check**

I have updated some js code to make it work.

```js
    var count = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function () {

        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="trrows">';

        html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select name="med_name[]" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option> <option value="1"> Option 1 </option><option value="2"> Option 2 </option><option value="3"> Option 3 </option><option value="4"> Option 4 </option><option value="5"> Option 5 </option></select></td>';
        html += '<td id="mor"> <input type="text" name="morning[]" id="morning[]" class="form-control morning" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="noo"> <input type="text" name="noon[]" id="noon[]" class="form-control noon" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="nigh"> <input type="text" name="night[]" id="night[]" class="form-control night" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="period"> <input type="text" name="period[]" id="period[]" class="form-control period" /> </td>';
        html += '<td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove" >  -  </button> </td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#rows').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest("#trrows").remove();
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', 'select.med_name', function () {
      $('select[name*="med_name[]"] option').attr('disabled',false);
      $('select[name*="med_name[]"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('select[name*="med_name[]"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
             if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
             $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="medical">
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Medicine Name</th>
           <th>Morning</th>
           <th>Noon</th>
           <th>Night</th>
           <th>Period</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="rows">
     </tbody>
   </table>
   <br><br>

   <div align="right">
      <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn xs"> + </button>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks **Vishal**. Now it is working fine. Very well code segments. Thanks again. Have a save day

Comment: @MTMNASIK Happy to help you, please do upvote the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as your suggestion I am very glad to upvote your answer, but I couldn't, because, At least I have 15 reputations for upvote. Sure I will upvote, when my reputation will up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's very basic implementation

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    
    var value = $(this).val();
 
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=1> Option 1 </option>
  <option value=2> Option 1 </option>
  <option value=3> Option 1 </option>
</select>
```

**Edit: Here is your sample**

```js
var count = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="trrows">';

        html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select name="med_name[]" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option> <?php echo fill_select_box($conn, "0");  ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td id="mor"> <input type="text" name="morning[]" id="morning[]" class="form-control morning" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="noo"> <input type="text" name="noon[]" id="noon[]" class="form-control noon" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="nigh"> <input type="text" name="night[]" id="night[]" class="form-control night" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="period"> <input type="text" name="period[]" id="period[]" class="form-control period" /> </td>';
        html += '<td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove" >  -  </button> </td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#rows').append(html);
    });


    function addRow(rowIndex) {
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="trrows">';

        html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select name="med_name[' + rowIndex + ']" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option><option value="1"> Select Medicine1</option><option value="2"> Select Medicine2</option> </select></td>';
        html += '<td id="mor"> <input type="text" name="morning[]" id="morning[]" class="form-control morning" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="noo"> <input type="text" name="noon[]" id="noon[]" class="form-control noon" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="nigh"> <input type="text" name="night[]" id="night[]" class="form-control night" /> </td>';
        html += '<td id="period"> <input type="text" name="period[]" id="period[]" class="form-control period" /> </td>';
        html += '<td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove" >  -  </button> </td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#rows').append(html);
    }


    addRow(1);
    addRow(2);
    addRow(3);
    
 $('select[name*="med_name"]').change(function() {
    
    var value = $(this).val();
 
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=rows>

</table>
```

Comment: Here I have several select boxes, then I used ID for identify the specific select box. But same results

Comment: Yes you can do that just replace $('select') with your logic and rest would work

Comment: Select change to what?

Comment: when I change to ID, but the same results

Comment: @MTMNASIK I have updated the solution with your sample, just modified so that it would in javascript

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I want to fetch the data from database and load into select option that I have done. That is why I used this `html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select name="med_name[]" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option> <?php echo fill_select_box($conn, "0");  ?></select></td>';`

Comment: Then you use selector as special class so that for all items it would work

Comment: @MTMNASIK have updated solution with matching name and added 3 rows and it works, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your corporation. I have got several ideas from you.

Comment: Did this code not work? because I thought this did what you expected compared to the accepted answer :)

Comment: Same results my dear

Comment: Inside the select option, I fetch data from database. That is why I am looking for